# Getting a modal target attribute with string that has white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

Why do I keep getting a concatenated string? In the example below I want to get the `data-name` in the modal and I successfully manage to do that. The problem is when I try to get a string that has white space in it, for example `"white space"`, then the only string I get is `"white"`.

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-name="white space">Example</button>
```

```js
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  // get data-id attribute of the clicked element
  var name = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-name');

  // populate the text-box
  $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="textbox"]').val(name) 
});
```

Comment: can you add the full html you have? Like an working example, we can play around?

Comment: Your logic works fine, assuming the selectors are working as you expect them to be: http://jsfiddle.net/p4nebdg1/.

Comment: It worked for me too. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pg3an7L1/2/).

Comment: thank you for cooperation i solve the problem by fetching the data correctly in the button.